# Best way to compare a string to a deeply nested string value of an object property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm writing tests for a function and I'm running into an issue. I can messily achieve what I want, but I want to make it a little more dynamic.

For instance, if I have,

```
import { mapValues, isObject, forIn } from 'lodash';

const trimText = field => typeof field === 'string' ? field.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') : field;

const trimFields: any = data => mapValues(data, (element, k) => isObject(element) ? trimFields(element) : trimText(element));

const simpleObject = {
  fieldA: [' simple trim ', 'simple trim'],
  fieldB: [' new\n   line trim ', 'new\n   line trim'],
  fieldC: [' \n\ts\n\t\n ', 's']
};
```

I can write a test for it as,

```
describe('Simple object /', () => {
  const objectToTrim: any = {};
  forIn(simpleObject, ([raw], key) => {
    objectToTrim[key] = raw;
  });

  const trimmedObject = trimFields(objectToTrim);
  forIn(trimmedObject, (value, key) => {
    it(`Should have properly trimmed ${value} into ${simpleObject[key][1]}`, () => {
      expect(value).toEqual(simpleObject[key][1]);
    });
  });
});
```

But now, I'm running into an issue with a complex object. For instance, if I have:

```
const complexObject: any = {
  fieldA: [
    { subfieldA: ' simple trim ' },
    'simple trim'
  ],
  fieldB: [
    {
      subfieldB: {
        subSubFieldB: ' new\n   line trim '
      }
    },
    'new\n   line trim'
  ],
  fieldC: [
    {
      subfieldC: {
        subSubFieldC: {
          subSubSubfieldC: ' \n\ts\n\t\n '
        }
      }
    },
    's'
  ]
};
```

I'm not sure how to test this. Is there a way to write the test the same as for the simple object, but by somehow finding the nested value? With lodash, for example, (because I'm already using that anyway), is it possible to find `subSubSubfieldC` in `fieldC` and then compare it to `complexObject[key][1]` as I have done in the `expect(...)` with `simpleObject[key][1]`?

Comment: have you considered flattening the object?

Comment: I have not, you mean flatten it after the recursive `trimFields`, right? I will try that.

Comment: In my opinion, tests should be as simple as possible to reduce the chance of errors. Try following the arrange, act, assert method. First in your test create your object, then run the trimFields object and assert that it’s what you expected. And by assert you should hardcode the result that you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jest's it.each to provide the different inputs (avoiding lodash usage) to provide the different paths to in the object and `.toHaveProperty` to match the path and the value

example (not tested):

```
describe('Complex object', () => {
  let result;
  beforeAll(() => {
    result = trimFields({
      fieldA: [
        { subfieldA: ' simple trim ' },
        'simple trim'
      ],
      fieldB: [
        {
          subfieldB: {
            subSubFieldB: ' new\n   line trim '
          }
        },
        'new\n   line trim'
      ],
      fieldC: [
        {
          subfieldC: {
            subSubFieldC: {
              subSubSubfieldC: ' \n\ts\n\t\n '
            }
          }
        },
        's'
      ]
    })
  })

  it.each([
    ['fieldA.0.subfieldA', 'simple trim'],
    ['fieldA.1', 'simple trim'],
    ['fieldB.0.subfieldB.subSubFieldB', 'new line trim']
  ])('should have property %s with trimmed value %s', (path, value) => {
    expect(result).toHaveProperty(path, value);
  })
})
```